# Can iATS "pause" recurring contributions?

Tags: recurring-contributions, iats, iatspayments

I know that you can't pause contributions from within CiviCRM with processors that aren't token-based - but can you with iATS?

If you can't do it within CiviCRM, can it be done from within the iATS portal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and No.

Here's two options:

1. if you want to Pause for a specified period of time (say 6months) -> hit Edit on the Recurring Contribution and advance the next scheduled contribution date by +6months.
2. if you want to pause indefinitely -> you could hit Cancel on the Recurring Contribution. And then (later on when ready to "un-pause") -> set the Recurring Series to In Progress again [that can not be done via the CiviCRM UI, but using API Explorer or with direct database access it's a simple query).

No pause on the iATS side of things.

Answer (score 0):

I do this regularly right in CiviCRM by editing the recurring contribution and setting the "Next Scheduled Contribution Date" to be when I want the pause to end, works great.